How does the Mint function work in compound V2?
In compound v2, the mint process is that an EOA calls the mint function of a cToken contract, then finally the cToken contract calls the doTransferIn and token.transferFrom functions. The question is that, this should not work because inside the transferFrom funtion, it checks if the msg.sender(which in this case is the cToken contract) is the minter(which in this case is the EOA), and if not, it won't transfer any money. So how could it work?
 //cToken(cDai) contract
function doTransferIn(address from, uint amount) virtual override internal returns (uint) {
    // Read from storage once
    address underlying_ = underlying;
    EIP20NonStandardInterface token = EIP20NonStandardInterface(underlying_);
    uint balanceBefore = EIP20Interface(underlying_).balanceOf(address(this));
    token.transferFrom(from, address(this), amount);

    bool success;
    assembly {
        switch returndatasize()
            case 0 {                       // This is a non-standard ERC-20
                success := not(0)          // set success to true
            }
            case 32 {                      // This is a compliant ERC-20
                returndatacopy(0, 0, 32)
                success := mload(0)        // Set `success = returndata` of override external call
            }
            default {                      // This is an excessively non-compliant ERC-20, revert.
                revert(0, 0)
            }
    }
    require(success, "TOKEN_TRANSFER_IN_FAILED");

    // Calculate the amount that was *actually* transferred
    uint balanceAfter = EIP20Interface(underlying_).balanceOf(address(this));
    return balanceAfter - balanceBefore;   // underflow already checked above, just subtract
}

//Dai.sol
function transferFrom(address src, address dst, uint wad)
    public returns (bool)
{
    require(balanceOf[src] >= wad, "Dai/insufficient-balance");
    if (src != msg.sender && allowance[src][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {
        require(allowance[src][msg.sender] >= wad, "Dai/insufficient-allowance");
        allowance[src][msg.sender] = sub(allowance[src][msg.sender], wad);
    }
    balanceOf[src] = sub(balanceOf[src], wad);
    balanceOf[dst] = add(balanceOf[dst], wad);
    emit Transfer(src, dst, wad);
    return true;
}


Referencing the cDAI token contract found in the Compound v2 documentation, I see that the mint() function calls another function inside the same contract called delegateToImplementation():
function mint(uint mintAmount) external returns (uint) {
        bytes memory data = delegateToImplementation(abi.encodeWithSignature("mint(uint256)", mintAmount));
        ...
    }

Which calls another function called delegateTo():
function delegateToImplementation(bytes memory data) public returns (bytes memory) {
        return delegateTo(implementation, data);
    }

This function uses delegatecall to call the implementation contract address:
function delegateTo(address callee, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = callee.delegatecall(data);
        ...
    }

The implementation contract's mint() function calls mintInternal():
function mint(uint mintAmount) override external returns (uint) {
        mintInternal(mintAmount);
        ...
    }

Which calls mintFresh():
function mintInternal(uint mintAmount) internal nonReentrant {
        ...
        mintFresh(msg.sender, mintAmount);
    }

Which then calls doTransferIn():
function mintFresh(address minter, uint mintAmount) internal {
        ...
        uint actualMintAmount = doTransferIn(minter, mintAmount);
        ...
    }

Finally, this calls token.transferFrom() on the underlying ERC20 token, in this case DAI:
function doTransferIn(address from, uint amount) virtual override internal returns (uint) {
        ...
        EIP20NonStandardInterface token = EIP20NonStandardInterface(underlying_);
        token.transferFrom(from, address(this), amount);
        ...
    }

The context is preserved while calling functions within the same contract and while using delegatecall, but once the cDAI implementation contract directly calls transferFrom on the DAI contract, msg.sender becomes the proxy contract.
While DAI does check if msg.sender is the src address, it doesn't completely prevent the two from being unequal. What is happening, is that the DAI contract is ensuring that if src isn't the one transferring tokens, that at least src has used approve() to allow the msg.sender to transfer the tokens. You can view the past cDAI mint transactions on etherscan to see real examples.
if (src != msg.sender && allowance[src][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {
        require(allowance[src][msg.sender] >= wad, "Dai/insufficient-allowance");
        allowance[src][msg.sender] = sub(allowance[src][msg.sender], wad);
    }

What this conditional is saying is that if address src isn't msg.sender, AND src hasn't approved msg.sender to spend the maximum amount of tokens possible, then check to ensure that src has at least approved msg.sender to spend wad amount of tokens.

If msg.sender tries to spend more than allowed, revert with the string error message.
Subtract wad, the tokens being spent by msg.sender, from the amount of allowance given to them by src.

